# Haskell - implement a function for a given signature

Tags: haskell, null, char, signature

I have to implement an example function with following signature:

```
[[([Char],  a,  b)]] -> (a  ->  b  ->  Char)  ->  ([Char],  b  ->  a  ->  Char)
```

So I attempt this way:

```
funcD [[([' '],x,y)]] uFunc0D = ([' '],  uFunc1D)
    where
        uFunc0D x y = ' '   
        uFunc1D y x  = ' '
```

but, whe I invoke the type of it with

```
:t funcD
```

it returns

```
funcD :: [[([Char], t1, t2)]] -> t -> ([Char], t3 -> t4 -> Char)
```

**Few questions:**

1. Why does it return `t` for the 2nd argument rather than `(a  ->  b  ->  Char)`?
2. I passed `' '` for Char and it works, however I want to pass an empty char-arg like `''`, but it doesn't work.
3. Why do I get t3 and t4 rather than t1 and t2 in the result signature?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
My next try:

```
funcD1 [[([' '],x,y)]] (uFunc0D x y = ' ' where _ = x y) = ([' '],  uFunc1D)
    where
        uFunc1D y x  = ' '
```

Comment: Rather than throwing syntax at the wall and seeing what sticks, I suggest you study up on Haskell syntax. For example, try [this chapter of Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions). In particular, pay attention to the difference between patterns and expressions and which ones go where.

Answer (score 4):

1. `uFunc0D` is not used (you shadow the argument in the `where` clause with a function that has identical name)
2. `' '` denotes a character literal, it must contain one character. You might be thinking of strings, in which case `""` is the empty string.
3. The arguments to `uFunc1D` is not related at all to the input arguments `x` and `y`, so they are free to be different types.

Edit:

you have to use the arguments in the expression (right hand side of the equal sign) for it to affect the return type. Your declaration in the `where` clause introduces `uFunc0D` and `uFunc1D`. The declaration of `uFunc0D` shadows the `uFunc0D` binding in the argument (left hand side) of the function, so that *even if* you were to mention `uFunc0D` in the rhs, it would be the one you declared in the where clause, not the argument.

Edit 2:

Here's an example, say you want a function `f :: (a -> b) -> a -> Char`

A naive attempt might be: `f f1 x = ' '`, but this will have a type `f :: a -> b -> Char`. Because the fact that `f1` should be a function isn't known (and in fact, you can pass something else as `f1`), and the fact that it takes in something the same type as the second argument is also not known.

Instead if you do: `f f1 x = ' ' where _ = f1 x`, then the type will be `f :: (a -> b) -> a -> Char`. In this case, the compiler knows that f1 must take at least one argument (since you are applying it to an argument), and the argument must have the type of the second argument (since you are applying it to the second argument).

Edit 3:

A word about haskell syntax.

Function declarations looks like this: `f arg1 arg2 = expr`

what goes into the position of `arg1` and `arg2` are patterns. what goes into `expr` are expressions.

if you see something like

```
f x = y
  where y = x + 1
```

what precedes the `where` clause is the expression, and what follows it are declarations visible in the expression. The newline before the `where` token is not significant, the above is identical to `f x = y where y = x + 1`.

What are patterns? Patterns lets you decompose a value into parts, and bind the parts to names.

`x` is a pattern, in `id x = x`, for instance. This means that `x` is bound to the first argument of `id`. the `x` on the right hand side is *not* a pattern, but rather an expression, one with the value of `x`, which was bound by the *pattern* in the left hand side.

`(a, b)` is another pattern, as in `fst (a, b) = a`. This pattern states that the input type should be a 2-tuple, with the first element bound to `a`, and the second bound to `b`.

In `mkPair a b = (a, b)`, `(a, b)` is an expression, not a pattern. It is an expression that has the value of a 2-tuple, whose first element is `a` (bound as the first argument on the left hand side), and second value `b` (bound as the second argument from the right hand side).

The argument positions of a function are always patterns, patterns may look like expressions, but they are not! Whether some bit of code is an expression or a pattern is determined by where it appears in relation to everything else, not by what it looks like.

Comment: thanks for your post. 1. if uFunc0D is shadowed the uFunc1D should be also shadowed since both are in where clause. But as you see, it returns the full signature for uFunc1D but not for uFunc0D. I tried also to write `uFunc0D x y = ' '` directly as a parameter without `where`, but of course it doesn't work. 3. In the required signature are `a` and `b`every where the same. Could you please tell me how I can fix these issues, so that I get the same signature?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right, but uFunc0D is an input argument. How should I put it in the right side of the equation? The right side is though the return part. Could you please explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Edited again with (hopefully) a helpful example.

Comment: thanks for the explaination, however I can't grasp it. I tried it, but anyhow it don't want to work. I edited my Answer, please read it. Thanks

Comment: You may wish to familiarize yourself with Haskell syntax, the `where` clause is used to create new bindings that are visible in the function body, you can't just put it inside the argument, which should only contain patterns.

Comment: Edited with a word about patterns vs expressions, you might want to look at chapters 2 and 3 of [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) for an introduction to the language.